# Как остановить таймер написать код для остановки?

Tags: c#, winforms

Помогите написать код для остановки таймера в Noarend_Click.

```
private void Arend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        date = DateTime.Now;
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 10;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(tickTimer);
        timer.Start();
        Timer.Visible = true;
        Arend.Visible = false;
        Noarend.Visible = true;
    }
    private  void tickTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        long tick = DateTime.Now.Ticks - date.Ticks;
        DateTime stopWatch = new DateTime();
        stopWatch = stopWatch.AddTicks(tick);
        Timer.Text = String.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss}", stopWatch);

    }

    private void Noarend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
private void Arend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    date = DateTime.Now;
    // timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 10;
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(tickTimer);
    timer.Start();
    Timer.Visible = true;
    Arend.Visible = false;
    Noarend.Visible = true;
}

private void Noarend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop(); //<---
}
```

Comment: пишет недопустимый термин<

Comment: пишет недопустимый термин ;

Comment: @nikita Это стрелочка, чтобы привлечь Ваше внимание к этой строке в ответе (что мне удалось :) ). В реальном коде она не нужна.

Comment: Всё заработало спасибо

Comment: @nikita Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Ещё вопрос как мне взять данные из таймера и вставить их для расчёта? Учитывая что допустим стоимость одной минуты равна допустим 10 рублей ?

Comment: @nikita Задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: Сделал    юююююююю