# Как мне взять данные с таймера?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как мне взять данные с таймера ? Учитавая то что допустим каждая минута равна 10руб.

```
private void Arend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    date = DateTime.Now;
    
    timer.Interval = 10;
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(tickTimer);
    timer.Start();
    Timer.Visible = true;
    Arend.Visible = false;
    Noarend.Visible = true;
}
private  void tickTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    long tick = DateTime.Now.Ticks - date.Ticks;
    DateTime stopWatch = new DateTime();
    stopWatch = stopWatch.AddTicks(tick);
    Timer.Text = String.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss}", stopWatch);

}

private void Noarend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
}
```

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1358285

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Сделал выполнено

Comment: Какие данные Вам нужны? Ни про какие рубли таймер не знает.

Comment: Мне надо вытащить из таймера минуты и часы и подставить потом в формулу.

Comment: Далее они мне будут нужны

Answer (score 1):

```
// берем случайную дату
var beginningDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2);

// узнаем  разницу между сейчас и взятой датой в тиках
var differenceTicks = DateTime.Now.Ticks - beginningDate.Ticks; 

// узнаем разницу в секундах
var differenceSec = differenceTicks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond * 1000;

var rublesPerMin = 10;

var rublesPerTimePeriodInMins = differenceSec / 60 * rublesPerMin;
```

Comment: Как вывести в textbox значение которое получилось?

Comment: Ну или в label.

Comment: @nikita `mylabel.Text = Convert.ToString(smthValue);`. Где `myLabel` - какой-то `Label` на форме, а `smthValue` - какое-то значение которое вы хотите записать в label (и соответственно показать на форме)

Comment: я label переименовал в Timer   Timer.Text = String.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss}", stopWatch);

Answer (score 0):

Вам придется делать это самому. Как здесь

```
long tick = DateTime.Now.Ticks - date.Ticks;
```

Comment: а как их в переменную то записать ?

Comment: Вы можете записать ?